# How do structures with parametized types inside a C++ template get initialized?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to figure out how to initialize a structure inside a template

```
template<class T>
class Base
{
  struct Foo
  {
    T one,
    T two
  };

  Foo test;

public:

  Base()
  {
    test = {};
  };
}
```

Is this the correct way to get the members of the structure to be value initialized in pre C++ 11?

Are there other ways?

Edit: My apologies.  I messed up the code.  There is actually an instance of the struct in the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You are assigning, not initializing.

Initialise it like you'd initialize a member in *any* class:

```
Base() : test() {};
```